# PGP encrypted external Toshiba drive

Tags: external-hard-drive, passwords, encryption, disk-encryption, pgp

I encrypted my external hard drive, a 350 GB Toshiba with PGP disk encryption and i forgot the password.
Question: Is it possible to use a brute force attack (considering i know part of the password), using a dictionary, to recover the password? 
Also, i did not create a key to recover the password from...
Thank you!

Comment: A brute-force attack, and a dictionary attack, are two different things. You do not use a dictionary for a brute-force attack.

Comment: Has it occurred to you that if you can break the encryption ... it was pointless to be using it in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. With tools [like this here](http://www.elcomsoft.com/efdd.html) for example.

Comment: Yep I got Elcomsoft all right but the Distributed Password Recovery tool only helps with passworded documents like PDFs etc. PGP opens a dialog box for password entry, when the external drive is plugged in. How do I make it work from here? Thank you!

Comment: You close that password dialogue box and use the tool to browse to the file on the disk to decrypt it. If it's whole disk encryption, you might have to use a different PC or uninstall PGP first. See the manual: http://www.elcomsoft.com/help/efdd/pgp_and_truecrypt.html